# Python Beautifulsoup get previous element using find_all_previous

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to identify some size in specific category, for example, I would like to scrap '(2)募入決定額' under the category '6．価格競争入札について'  and '7．非競争入札について'
But somehow the structure for these are a little bit tricky as there is no hierarchy for these elements.

The website I use is :

```
https://www.mof.go.jp/jgbs/auction/calendar/nyusatsu/resul20211101.htm
```

And I tried the following code but nothing print out.

```
rows = soup.findAll('span')
    for cell in r:       
        if "募入決定額" in cell:      
        a=rows[0].find_all_previous("td")
        for i in a:
            print(a.get('text'))
```

Much appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

---

You could select all `<td>` that contains `募入決定額` and from there its nearest sibling `<td>` that contains a `<span>`.

```
soup.select('td:-soup-contains("募入決定額") ~ td>span')
```

To get its previous categorie iterate over all previous `<tr>`:

```
[x.td.text for x in e.find_all_previous('tr') if x.td.span][0]
```

Read more about [`bs4 and css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and under [dev.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.mof.go.jp/jgbs/auction/calendar/nyusatsu/resul20211101.htm'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url).content)
for e in soup.select('td:-soup-contains("募入決定額") ~ td>span'):
    print(e.text)

    # or 
    print([x.td.text for x in e.find_all_previous('tr') if x.td.span][0],e.text)
```

##### Output

```
2兆1,205億円
4億8,500万円
4,785億円
```

or

```
6． 2兆1,205億円
7． 4億8,500万円
8． 4,785億円
```

Comment: Hi HedgeHog, thanks for your help! May I ask the syntax for ```td:-soup-contains("募入決定額") ~ td>```, sorry I am new to bs4, may I ask what are ```~``` and ```-```stand for?  And I see```募入決定額"```is in ```span```tag, why should we use ```td```tag?

Comment: Hi you are right I missed but added referencing docs part for `css selectors` to my answer. Concerning second part - We select `<td>` cause in next step we referenz to one of its siblings else we have to go back to the `span` parent and then finding the sibling with expected information.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply and your assistance! But I am confused as I only want to grab the nearest the category, but why ```find_all_previous```works? is there a way to grab like the second previous tag? for ```if x.td.span``` I think it returns all ```tr```contains ```td>span```, but why the category name such as  ```価格競争入札について```does not show up

Comment: Simply because `x.td` refers to its direct child, but you can also reference the next sibling from that one `x.td.find_next('td').text`

Comment: thank you so much for your help! may I ask if you could help me to vote the question? as it currently shows -1 lol